# How to insert input values into store on buttonclick in extjs

Tags: extjs

I am implementing project in extjs. i want to insert textfields values into store on ok button click. i have designed forms as-

Model-

```
Ext.define('AM.model.User', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['Question', 'Option']
});
```

Store-

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'User',
    proxy: {
               type: 'localstorage',
           }
    autoLoad: true
});
```

Controller-

```
Ext.define('AM.controller.Users', {
     extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
     views: [
                'user.List',
            ],
     store: ['Users'],
     model: ['User'],
     init: function() {
        this.control({
            "button": {
                click: this.onButtonClick
            }
        });
      },    
      onButtonClick: function(button){
      var form = button.up('form').getForm ();

      // Validate the form
      if (form.isValid ()) {
        var values = form.getFieldValues ();
        store.add ({
          Question: values.Question,
          Option: values.Option
        });
      }
      else {
          alert("Insert values in textfields");       
      } 
    }
    });
```

View-

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    title: 'Question-option',
    width: 300,
    bodyPadding: 10,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),        
     items: [{
        xtype: 'textfield',
        name: 'Question',
        fieldLabel: 'Question',
        allowBlank: false  
    }, 
    {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        name: 'Option',
        fieldLabel: 'Option',
    },
    {xtype: 'button', text: 'Ok'}]
```

But when i am adding above onbuttonclick action into my controller code,it is not displaying any input fields. So can someone please help me in order to display view and insert those imputs into store.

Comment: does this help? http://jsfiddle.net/dbrin/wULET/3/

Comment: please look through your previous questions and mark best answers as accepted by clicking the hollow checkmark. thank you.

Comment: Thanx dbrin for help. But example given in link' jsfiddle.net/dbrin/wULET/3 ' is having store with somewhat static values. I want to insert view form's Question and option's textfields values into store and display that store in gridview. So please tell me how to insert textfields inputs into store. i am using store with localstoragproxy. My project code is as provided above...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have gone through the snippet above because of following reasons.
 1) Json Syntax errors.
 2) You have messed up Ext.define and Ext.Create

I have updated your scripts and tested it on my local machine. Its working!

//Controller  - app/controller

```
 Ext.define('AM.controller.Users', {
        extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

         views: [
                    'user.List'
                ],
         stores: ['Users'],
         models: ['User'],
        init: function() {
            console.log('controller initialized');
            this.control({
                'viewport panel button': {
                    'click': this.onButtonClick
                }
            });
        },

        onButtonClick: function(button, e, eOpts ) {
            var form = button.up('form').getForm();
            var model = this.getModel('AM.model.User');

          // Validate the form
          if (form.isValid ()) {
            var question = model.create(form.getFieldValues());
            console.log(question.data);
          }
          else {
              alert("Insert values in textfields");       
          } 
        }

    },function(){
        console.log("Users Controller created");
    });
```

// View  - app/view/user/list

```
 Ext.define('AM.view.user.List', {
        extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
        alias: 'widget.userlist',
        title: 'Question-option',
        width: 300,
        bodyPadding: 10,
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),        
         url: 'some url',// in case of ajax
        //  initComponent: function(){
        items: [{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            name: 'Question',
            fieldLabel: 'Question',
            allowBlank: false  // requires a non-empty value
        }, {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            name: 'Option',
            fieldLabel: 'Option'
            vtype: 'email'  // requires value to be a valid email address format
        },
        {
        xtype:'button',
        text:'Save'

       }
        ]

    },function(){
    console.log("List view was created");
    });
```

Update your JS files and run! If you face any issues comment here

Comment: Thanx for you help patton sir.but when i am replacing my controller and view file completely with below code as per given by Patton sir,but then it is not displaying any view. In cosole window output is displaying as-
List view was created List.js:28
Users Controller created Users.js:33
controller initialized But there is no any input field is displaying.

Comment: Hmmm can you please show me your Ext.Application code along with viewport?